# Hazelcast TTL (Time to Live) is not working

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, ttl

In a spring boot environment, I have the following Hazelcast configuration.

```
@Bean
public Config hazelCastConfig() {
    final Config config = new Config().setInstanceName("hazelcast-cache")
            .addMapConfig(new MapConfig().setName("hazelcast-cache")
                    .setMaxSizeConfig(
                            new MaxSizeConfig(200, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                    .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU).setTimeToLiveSeconds(5))
            .setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

    final UserCodeDeploymentConfig distCLConfig = config.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
    distCLConfig.setEnabled(true)
            .setClassCacheMode(UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ClassCacheMode.ETERNAL)
            .setProviderMode(UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ProviderMode.LOCAL_CLASSES_ONLY);

    return config;
}
```

This is how use the cacheable in our code

```
@Cacheable(value = "presetCategoryMaster", key = "{#storeCode, #validDisplayFlag}")
public List<PresetCategoryMasterEntity> getPresetMasterCategoryForStoreCdAndValdiDisplayFlag(
        final Integer storeCode, final Short validDisplayFlag) {
              ----------------
              ----------------
}
```

But the TTL is never honored. We confirmed in the trace logs also. But after the first call, once the cache entries are made, it never gets evicted unless you explicitly call CacehEvict() or CachePut(). All though we have TTL value to 5 secs, the cache is not cleared even after an hour.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The cache name is `presetCategoryMaster`

```
@Cacheable(value = "presetCategoryMaster"
```

The configuration uses `hazelcast-cache`, so doesn't match.

```
new MapConfig().setName("hazelcast-cache")
```

You can use the Management Center or [getDistributedObjects()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.1.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#getDistributedObjects--)
call to find out what's created and watch for them expiring.